# Mule 4- Salesforce connector Basic Auth connection failed

Tags: salesforce, mulesoft, mule4, mule-connector

I'm trying to set a Salesforce configuration for the connector using "Basic Auth" authentication, but I got `SALESFORCE:CONNECTIVITY error`:

> Encountered HTML Content when looking for http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/:Envelope

I know for a fact that all fields are correct (username, password, security token, authentication URL).

```xml
<salesforce:sfdc-config name="Salesforce_Config" doc:name="Salesforce Config" doc:id="3dd44e06-b340-4219-bb00-b7d714ff4e12" >
        <salesforce:basic-connection username="xxx@force.com" password="xxxxxxx" securityToken="copied from the email received" url="https://login.sakesforce.com/services/Soap/u/53.0" objectTTL="24" objectTTLTimeoutUnit="HOURS"/>
</salesforce:sfdc-config>
```

I checked online trying to sort out, and found some answer requiring to set up *error log* of Salesforce using Apex, which is too complicated. There's also someone said it could be a firewall issue, but how?

Comment: If you don't share details then we can not help you. Please share the XML of the connector configuration with the credentials masked. Note that even with more details if the issue is caused by something in the network we cannot help anyway since we don't know anything about that. Also infrastructure is not a valid topic here.

Comment: Most probably a networking problem in your network.